# Is it possible to set a function's environment while runtime in R?

Tags: r, function

If you define functions, they are all part of the `Global Environment` by default.
I wonder, whether there is a way, to set a function's parent environmet to the calling environment (while
runtime - a function might be called in different places!). Thus, in case of nested functions,
it should become possible, to define a variable in only one envrionment and I would expect for an example like

```
fun1 <- function() {
  # variable "my_env" defined only in this environment
  subfun() # calls subsubfun()
  return(NULL)
}
```

an output of `exists("my_env", different_environments)` like

```
# [1] "fun1"
# [1] "===="
# [1] TRUE #     Only here: "here", in this function
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
# [1] " subfun"
# [1] " ======"
# [1] FALSE
# [1] TRUE #     Only here: "parent environment", in calling function
# [1] FALSE
# [1] "  subsubfun"
# [1] "  ========="
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
# [1] TRUE #     Only here: "parent-parent environment", in the function calling the function
```

From the docs `?parent.frame`

> **sys.parent** returns the number of the parent frame if n is 1 (the
> default), the grandparent if n is 2, and so on. See also the ‘Note’.
> (...) **parent.frame(n)** is a convenient shorthand for
> sys.frame(sys.parent(n)) (implemented slightly more efficiently).
>
> Note
> Strictly, **sys.parent** and **parent.frame** refer to the context of
> the parent interpreted function. So internal functions (which may or
> may not set contexts and so may or may not appear on the call stack)
> may not be counted, and S3 methods can also do surprising things.
> Beware of the effect of lazy evaluation: these two functions look at
> the call stack at the time they are evaluated, not at the time they
> are called. Passing calls to them as function arguments is unlikely to
> be a good idea.

Some example to start with from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63628854/5784831), which does not work, as all functions are part of the global environment.

```
subfun0 <- function() {
  e <- parent.frame()
  attr(e, "name") <- "my_env"
  assign("my_env", 1,
         envir = parent.frame(),
         inherits = FALSE, immediate = TRUE)
  return(NULL)
}

subsubfun <- function() {
  print("  subsubfun")
  print("  =========")
  print(exists("my_env"))
  print(exists("my_env", parent.frame()))
  env <- parent.frame()
  print(exists("my_env", parent.env(env)))
  return(NULL)
}

subfun <- function() {
  print(" subfun")
  print(" ======")
  print(exists("my_env"))
  print(exists("my_env", parent.frame()))
  env <- parent.frame()
  print(exists("my_env", parent.env(env)))
  subsubfun()
  return(NULL)
}

fun1 <- function() {
  print("fun1")
  print("====")
  subfun0()
  print(exists("my_env"))
  print(exists("my_env", parent.frame()))
  env <- parent.frame()
  print(exists("my_env", parent.env(env)))
  subfun()
  return(NULL)
}

fun1()
```

---

(I just realized, that I had a completely wrong picture of "calling environment" in mind and my questions is, could I make "my picture" work in R.)

Comment: I don't understand why you would need it.. why can't you just pass arguments to your functions? Or why don't you pass the environment as an argument?

Comment: @Edo I would like track special variables without the need to rewrite every function. I think this would add quite some nice flexibility. The concrete trigger was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63552940/5784831) really good question...

Comment: Track..? What do you mean? ps: what about `environment<-` to change the environment of a function? es: `a<-function()i`
`b<-function(){i<-1;a()};b()` Returns Error
`d<-function(){environment(a)<-environment();i<-1;a()};d()` Returns [1] 1

Comment: by "track" you mean that you wanna see how the value of a variable that is passed between several functions changes in time?

Comment: @Edo You are right, "track" is misleading, I mean you can create a variable, and you know "all the time", that if it exists, it has to exist in a certain environment and a certain name. I tried `environment() <- rlang::caller_env()` but without success. And from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49619767/5784831) I am not sure anymore, whether my plan is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you get exactly what you're looking for:

```
subfun0 <- function() {
    e <- parent.frame()
    attr(e, "name") <- "my_env"
    assign("my_env", 1,
                 envir = parent.frame(),
                 inherits = FALSE, immediate = TRUE)
    return(NULL)
}

subsubfun <- function() {
    print("  subsubfun")
    print("  =========")
    print(exists("my_env"))
    print(exists("my_env", parent.frame()))
    print(exists("my_env", parent.frame(2)))
    return(NULL)
}

subfun <- function() {
    print(" subfun")
    print(" ======")
    print(exists("my_env"))
    print(exists("my_env", parent.frame()))
    print(exists("my_env", parent.frame(2)))
    subsubfun()
    return(NULL)
}

fun1 <- function() {
    print("fun1")
    print("====")
    subfun0()
    print(exists("my_env"))
    print(exists("my_env", parent.frame()))
    print(exists("my_env", parent.frame(2)))
    subfun()
    return(NULL)
}

fun1()
```

```
[1] "fun1"
[1] "===="
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] " subfun"
[1] " ======"
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] "  subsubfun"
[1] "  ========="
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
NULL
```

The point is that: `parent.frame(2)` is not equal to `parent.env(parent.frame())`

Comment: Can you explain, why "`parent.frame(2)` is not equal to `parent.env(parent.frame())`"? I added the docs to the question and to me this is not really clear - your result of course is! (See my edit to the question.)

Comment: I believe that [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) and [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#calling-environments) you will find a far better explanation than whatever I could say. In particular, mind the difference between calling environment and binding environment

Comment: I meant "calling env and enclosing env". that's where the difference matters for your example.